# How to broadcast Eigen::Tensor to higher dimensions?

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor

I would like to broadcast an N-dimensional Eigen::Tensor to an (N+1)-dimensional Tensor to do some simple algebra. I cannot figure out the correct syntax.

I have already tried broadcasting in-place, and assigning the result of the broadcast to a new tensor. Both fail to compile with substantial template error messages (compiling on Mac with Apple Clang 10.0.1). I think the relevant problem is that the compiler cannot find a valid overload for `.resize()`. I have tried the broadcasting operation with both `std::array`, `Eigen::array`, and `Eigen::Tensor::Dimensions for the type of the dimensions but none worked:

```cpp
    srand(time(0));
    Eigen::Tensor<float, 3> t3(3, 4, 5);
    Eigen::Tensor<float, 2> t2(3, 4);
    t3.setRandom();
    t2.setRandom();
    // In-place operation
    t3 /= t2.broadcast(std::array<long, 3>{1, 1, 5}); // Does not compile
    // With temporary
    Eigen::Tensor<float, 3> t2b = t2.broadcast(Eigen::array<long, 3>{1, 1, 5}); // Does not compile either
    t3 /= t2b;
```

Is this something Eigen::Tensor does not support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Broadcast](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html#title89) works in a slightly different way. It takes an argument specifying how many times the tensor should be repeated in each dimension. This means both that the argument array length is equal to the tensor rank, and that the resulting tensor has the same rank as the original.

However, this is close to what you had intended originally: just add a reshape!

For instance:

```cpp
    Eigen::Tensor<float, 1> t1(3);
    t1 << 1,2,3;
    auto copies  = std::array<long,1> {3};
    auto shape   = std::array<long,2> {3,3};
    Eigen::Tensor<float,2> t2 = t1.broadcast(copies).reshape(shape);
```

Should result in a 3 by 3 "matrix" containing

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Comment: Thank you - I confirm this works. In my opinion it's an annoyance that broadcast can't do this in one go (there are various ways to do it in one step in Numpy or Matlab). But I have a solution so on I go.

Comment: The link appears to be broken.